# iOS 16: AVPlayerViewController's contentOverlayView has bad layout

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller

After the release of iOS 16 we started getting feedback that the video controls were no longer appearing. Sure enough, testing with a device with iOS 16 was giving us different results than 15.

When hitting the screen with the UI Debugger I found:

[image: UI Debgger]

The `contentOverlayView` was no longer the same size as the containing `AVPlayerViewController` view. Inspecting it shows:

[image: Constraints]

So, the `contentOverlayView` has ambiguous height/Y constraints, but this is a view controlled by `AVPlayerViewController`. Again, iOS 15 and earlier didn't have this issue (and the code has remained the same for a few years now).

Here is the existing code that:

1. Clears the `contentOverlayView` of any existing subviews
2. Initializes and sets up the custom video controls for the app
3. Adds the controls to the `contentOverlayView` setting the anchors.
4. It then adds the player's view to a passed in superview and sets the anchors for that.

```
    override func addTo(superview: UIView) {
        
        if let contentOverlayView = moviePlayer.contentOverlayView {
            contentOverlayView.subviews.forEach({$0.removeFromSuperview()})
            movieControls = ADMovieControlsView(delegate: self, subtitles: subtitleUrl)
            if let movieControls = movieControls {
                movieControls.allowFastForward = fastforwardingAllowed
                movieControls.allowsDismissal = allowsDismissal
                movieControls.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                contentOverlayView.addSubview(movieControls)

                movieControls.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentOverlayView.topAnchor).isActive = true
                movieControls.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentOverlayView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
                movieControls.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentOverlayView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
                movieControls.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentOverlayView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            }
        }
        
        superview.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
        moviePlayer.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        moviePlayer.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor).isActive = true
        moviePlayer.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        moviePlayer.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        moviePlayer.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Does anyone know if this is a known iOS 16 bug or if something changed that requires code updating? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by removing:

```
moviePlayer.contentOverlayView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

From the initialization function. Something changed in iOS 16 that created issues using this.